# Get the list of Facebook page IDs an account has access to using Python Facebook Marketing SDK

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

What would the call be to do this in the Python SDK?

Example of what part of the code I need, but can't find (this is wrong):

```
response = AdAccount(id).get_list_of_pages(fields, params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. `business_number` is Facebook business manager ID as an integer. `ad_account` is advertising account number with `act_` prefixed to the number.

```
params = {'business': business_number}
users = AdAccount(ad_account).get_assigned_users(params=params)
pages = AdAccountUser(users[0]['id']).get_pages()
```

Comment: This is giving me: `Tried accessing nonexisting field (accounts) on node type (BusinessUser)`